# Should [android-studio-2.0] be a synonym for [android-studio]?

Tags: discussion

[android-studio-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio-2.0) has 74 questions tagged to it of which nearly half are also tagged [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio). If you look at the short description of both tags their first lines are nearly verbatim:

**android-studio-2.0**

> Android Studio is the official IDE for Android application
>   development. In version 2.0 it is based on IntelliJ 14.

**android-studio**

> Android Studio is an official IDE targeted at Android development, based on IntelliJ IDEA from JetBrains.

Should these two tags be one?